# How to send a JSON response from an HTTP GET request in Golang?

Tags: json, go

I am learning how to build a server with Go, and wanted to know how to send a response back in JSON using Go's "encoding/json" library. Here is the code I have so far:

```
func HandlePosts (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    rs, err := http.Get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer rs.Body.Close()

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(rs.Body)
}
```

When I log this response in the browser's console, it just gives me an empty object. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What if you pass a string to the `Encode`?

Comment: First you don't want to encode the `rs.Body`, as that is just an `io.ReadCloser` implementation, not a data structure that you can serialize. Even if you read the response, the data returned from that url should already be json, so I don't understand what you would want to "encode". Do you want to just send the response back to the client, or are you trying to encode something else?

Comment: Yes, I am just trying to send the whole response back to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "encode" the `http.Repsonse.Body`. It's an `io.ReadCloser`, so you need to read from it.

In this case, the response is already json, so just send it back to the client.

```
io.Copy(w, rs.Body)
```